# toggle "required" attribute (of a hidden field) when an option is selected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do two things:

1. Show a hidden field if an option is selected, and hide that field if not (I have this part working - although if I use a variable it doesn't work)
2. If the option is selected, add a required attribute to the field that was displayed. When another option is selected, remove the required attribute.

Here's a fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/tucsonlabs/QCY2Q/

Comment: it looks like its working to me. Although, you probably shouldn't prefix all your variables and function names with a $... that's kind of confusing considering the $ is used by jQuery as a function name.

Comment: I use a $ to show that it's a jquery object. I think that's pretty standard isn't it?

Comment: Could be, I guess I never really noticed.

Comment: @JonathanRowny It's commonly used for indicating that the variable holds a jQuery-wrapped object.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Good to know. How about for function names? In the provided fiddle the function does something with jQuery, but it is not returning a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: @JonathanRowny Haven't seen that usage yet. Using it for function names does not feel like a good idea to me, it is not as clear as it is with a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($("#aCard").filter(":selected"))` this will always pass through because jQuery always return an object and anything non zero or not null or undefined passes through `if` block.

Use this `if ($("#aCard").filter(":selected").length > 0)`, you can even use variable to show the required element in your fiddle take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/QCY2Q/1/

Comment: Technically, there should only be one element of each id.  If this is going to be the case, you can use ($("#aCard").is(":selected"))

Comment: @Dave - That's correct `is(":selected")` is much better. But I just pin pointed what OP was doing wrong in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli. That was exactly the problem, they're both working now!