# jQuery validates input fields only in the first row of loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

This is my first post here so I apologize in advance if the formatting is wrong.

I am working on a form that pulls data from MySQL using a loop and outputs it to HTML page. The user then has the option to approve or deny the entries, and based on user selection validation should be required or optional. My current code will validate correctly, but only for the first row being outputted from the loop. I am trying to validate all rows. I have tried using a while loop and foreach statement with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**My Loop & Form:**

```
  //connect  to the database 
  $db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error()); 
  //-select  the database to use 
  $mydb=mysqli_select_db($db,"my_db") or die(mysql_error());
  //-query  the database table 
  $sql="SELECT id, date, client_name, client_number, date_completed, status FROM clients WHERE client_name LIKE '%" . $search  ."%' OR status LIKE '%" . $search  ."%' "; 
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
  $result=mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
  //-count  results 
  $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($rows=mysqli_num_rows($result)) { 
  echo  "<h2 style='margin-left: 10em;margin-bottom: -0.4em;'><br><br><br>" . $rows . " result(s) found for " . $search . "</h2><br />"; 
  }elseif($rows=mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo  "<h2 style='margin-left: 10em;margin-bottom: -0.4em;'><br><br><br>0 result(s) found for " . $search . "</h2><br />";        
  }
  //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

  $id=$row['id'];
  $date=$row['date'];
  $client_name=$row['client_name'];
  $client_number=$row['client_number'];
  $date_completed=$row['date_completed'];
  $status=$row['status'];

    echo "<form  method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>";
    echo "<table border='0'>";
    echo  "<tr>\n";
    echo  "<td>Timestamp</td><td>Client Name</td><td>Client Number</td>Status</td><td>Date Completed & Returned</td><td>Upload Zip Files</td>\n";
    echo  "</tr>";
    echo  "<tr>\n";
    echo  "<td readonly class='date'>$date</td>\n";
    echo  "<td><input readonly type='text' id='client_name' name='client_name' value='$client_name'></td>\n";
    echo  "<td><input readonly type='text' id='client_number' name='client_number' value='$client_number'></td>\n";
    echo  "<td><select id='status' name='status' aria-invalid='false'>
    <option value=''>Select an option</option>
    <option value='Denied'>Denied</option>
    <option value='Approved'>Approved</option>
    </select></td>\n"; 
    echo  "<td><input type='date' id='date_completed' name='date_completed_returned' value='$date_completed'></td>\n"; 
    echo  "<td><input type='file' id='upload' name='upload'></td>"; 
    echo  "<td class='submit'><input type='hidden' id='hidden' name='hidden' value='$client_name'><input type='submit' id='save' name='save' value='Save'></td>\n"; 
    echo  "</tr>"; 
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
   }
```

**My jQuery code:**

I am trying to make date_completed and upload fields required if user selects "Approved" under status field, and optional if he selects "Denied".

```
    <script>      
    $('#status').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == 'Approved')
    $("#date_completed").prop('required',true)  
    }).trigger("change"); // notice this line

    $('#status').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == 'Approved')
    $("#upload").prop('required',true)
    }).trigger("change"); // notice this line
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284580/toggle-required-attribute-of-a-hidden-field-when-an-option-is-selected-with

Also your question's title does not match the actual question you are asking

Comment: Your id isn't unique.

Comment: @SaurabhM Thanks for the reply...I changed the title. I will take a look at your link.

Comment: @KevinB Could you please elaborate or be more descriptive of how i can achieve this?

Comment: use unique id's in your rows. Only the first row is valid because id="status" can only happen once in an html page, hence why only the first row works. (i assume your loop is in php, and you have multiple forms, since you didn't provide your "loop" in the question.)

Comment: @KevinB Yes, you are correct. The loop is in php and I included it in the code above. Yes, the loop generates multiple forms. Is there a better approach I should be using? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Classnames would be more appropriate

Comment: @KevinB Thanks a lot man! Your suggestion to use class names instead of IDs worked like a charm. I will add the updated code so others can use it for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to KevinB I was able to find a solution to my problem.

I added class names for the input fields (status, date_completed, upload) I was trying to validate:

**Updated code below:**

```
echo "<form  method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>";
echo "<table border='0'>";
echo  "<tr>\n";
echo  "<td>Timestamp</td><td>Client Name</td><td>Client Number</td>Status</td><td>Date Completed & Returned</td><td>Upload Zip Files</td>\n";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>\n";
echo  "<td readonly class='date'>$date</td>\n";
echo  "<td><input readonly type='text' id='client_name' name='client_name' value='$client_name'></td>\n";
echo  "<td><input readonly type='text' id='client_number' name='client_number' value='$client_number'></td>\n";
echo  "<td><select id='status' name='status' class='status' aria-invalid='false'>
<option value=''>Select an option</option>
<option value='Denied'>Denied</option>
<option value='Approved'>Approved</option>
</select></td>\n"; 
echo  "<td><input type='date' id='date_completed' name='date_completed' class='date_completed' value='$date_completed'></td>\n"; 
echo  "<td><input type='file' id='upload' name='upload' class='upload'></td>"; 
echo  "<td class='submit'><input type='hidden' id='hidden' name='hidden' value='$client_name'><input type='submit' id='save' name='save' value='Save'></td>\n"; 
echo  "</tr>"; 
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

<script>
$('.status').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value == 'Approved')
$('.date_completed').prop('required',true)  
}).trigger("change"); // notice this line

$('.status').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value == 'Approved')
$('.upload').prop('required',true)
}).trigger("change"); // notice this line
</script>
```